# Linux headless auto detect monitor

Tags: linux, xorg

I have a kiosk system running Debian 11 with onboard GPU ( intel ), running using UEFI. The port for monitor is VGA.

Currently it logs in automatically using getty override ([reference](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/getty)) and call `startx` on tty1. We don't use a display manager.

Then it will start an `openbox-session` which then start vnc and single application there.

```bash
if [[ "$(tty)" == '/dev/tty1' ]]; then
    exec xinit $HOME/.xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc :0 vt1
fi
```

If the monitor is attached before boot then If I unplug and re plug the monitor later it will be show normally.

**But If there is no monitor plug during boot time. I won't be able to plug the monitor later** (the screen remains perpetually blank).

During both boot `openbox-session` and the application start successfully (can be view from vnc)

I try using xserver-driver-xorg-video-dummy and create /etc/X11/xorg.dummy.conf.
While all component is running, openbox-session somehow not loaded in the screen.
Currently didn't see any noticeable error in xorg.log

```bash
if [[ "$(tty)" == '/dev/tty1' ]]; then
    exec xinit $HOME/.xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc :0 vt1 -config xorg.dummy.conf
fi
```

xorg.dummy.conf [file](https://gist.github.com/divinity76/ce210b5dbcd9ea7d0585ac403caef577)

I try using Xvfb but I think it is not itended for this. While nothing broken the same problem still there.

Is it possible to achieve this ?
Currently If I forget to attach monitor when restart, I need to re restart it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in x server or display manager , actually it is in the

while xfce, gnome, etchave auto detect on monitor plug openbox doesn't have one
apparently using xrandr do the job ( autorandr not working )

in the .config/openbox/autostart

```bash
while true; do
    # Grep first connected display 
    FIRSTDISPLAY=$(xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }' | head -n 1)
    # Force on
    xrandr --output ${FIRSTDISPLAY} --auto
    # Kill dpms, require to rerun incase display replug
    xset -dpms
    xset s noblank
    xset s off
    sleep 1
done
```